# Store null values in List<Object> and List<?>

Tags: java, arraylist, null

Java's official documentation says:

> It's important to note that `List<Object>` and `List<?>` are not
> the same. You can insert an `Object`, or any subtype of `Object`, into a
> `List<Object>`. But you can only insert `null` into a `List<?>`.

Reference [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html).

This does not seem to be true. These two compile well and are usable (e.g. the list elements can be printed just fine):

```
List<Object> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(null);
l2.add(null);
```

Could you please say what the quoted sentence in the documentation really means?

Comment: You're not inserting objects, you're creating lists around predefined sets of objects.

Comment: Try adding elements after creating the lists, e.g. `l1.add(new Object())` and `l2.add(new Object())`. Adding `null` should work for both but adding anything but `null` to `l2` should make the compiler complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the text is correct. `null` is a valid value for any type, therefore, you can invoke `.add(null)` on any list, regardless of what is in the `<?>`. However, `null` (literally) is **the only** thing you can add to a `List<? extends Whatever>`. Given that literally `.add(null)` is generally useless, let's disregard it, which lets us simply state:

**You cannot add anything to a `List<?>`**.

That's the point of what the text is trying to explain.

Why can't you add anything? Because of this:

Let's say you have a `List<? extend Number>`. That means you can have a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<Double>` - those both 'work'. But given that you don't know what it is, if you just try to add an Integer object to this list (which is a Number), then maybe you're adding an Integer to a list of Doubles which would be an illegal move. Conclusion: `.add()` on a list of `<?>` or `<? extends something>` is not possible. (Except for the academic case of `null`).